# change numerical value in file to characters via awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm looking to replace the numerical values in a file with a new value provided by me.  Can be present in any part of the text, in some cases, it comes across as the third position but is not always necessarily the case. Also to try and save a new version of the file.

#### original format

```
A:fdg:user@server:r
A:g:1234:xtcy
A:d:1111:xtcy
```

#### modified format

```
A:fdg:user@server:rxtTncC
A:g:replaced_value:xtcy
A:d:replaced_value:xtcy
```

#### bash line command with awk:

```
awk -v newValue="newVALUE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} /:.:.*:/ && ~/^[0-9]+$/{~=newValue} 1' original_file.txt > replaced_file.txt
```

Comment: Why can't you just do something like `sed 's/:1234:/:user@server:/' <filename>` and so on? You can write all of your replacements to a script file, one per line, pass it to `sed -f`, and be done.

Comment: _with a new value provided by me_ How were you planning on providing those values?

Comment: @Thomas would like it if it just generally went through each line of the text, replace the numerical value, and saved it as a new text with the new value, I've just updated my question.

Comment: `echo "A:fi:1111:rx" | sed 's/:[0-9]:/:newvalue:/'` can i try something like this?

Comment: Of course, just add a `+` after `[0-9]` because you don't just want to match a single character but a sequence. You also have to use the `-E` options so that `sed` understands the `+` to mean "one ore more matches".

Comment: Instead of `echo` and a pipe, pass the filename as another argument to `sed` and use `> <outfile>` to save the result to `<outfile>`.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks will try to make this part of a bash script

Comment: No worries, you won't have any troubles using it inside a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
sed -E 's/\b[0-9]+\b/replaced_value/g' /path/to/infile > /path/to/outfile
```

Comment: Maybe `s/(^|:)[0-9]+($|:)/\1replaced_value\2/g` in case the numerical value is in the beginning or the end of line?

Comment: Good point. I would actually go for a slightly simpler approach, see updated answer.

Comment: The numerical values are going to be between the second `:` and third `:` Appreciate your feedback

Comment: `sed -E 's/\b[0-9]+\b/$NEW_VALUE/g' /path/to/infile > /path/to/outfile` I can just call previous value in bash script correct? sorry for the naive questions, quite new to the bash environment...

Comment: Yes, you can put that in a bash script, but if you want to use $VARIABLES, then you need to use double instead of single quotes (and maybe double backslashs instead of single backslashs). You wrote in your original question that it is not always necessarily the case that the numerical values are between the second and the third colon. If, however, you know that for sure, you could also write the following rule: `s/^([^:]*:[^:]*):[0-9]+:/\1:$NEWVALUE:/`

Comment: this is all based on regex expressions correct? I will update my question. thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an awk that asks you for replacement values for each numerical value it meets:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=":"                           # delimiters
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                   # loop all fields
        if($i~/^[0-9]+$/) {              # if numerical value found
            printf "Provide replacement value for %d: ",$i > "/dev/stderr"
            getline $i < "/dev/stdin"    # ask for a replacement
        }
}1' file_in > file_out                   # write output to a new file
```

Comment: wow very interactive script, thanks @james brown

Answer (score 3):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
A:fdg:user@server:rxtTncC
A:g:1234:xtcy
A:d:1111:xtcy
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{newvalue="replacement"}{gsub(/[[:digit:]]+/,newvalue);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
A:fdg:user@server:rxtTncC
A:g:replacement:xtcy
A:d:replacement:xtcy
```

Explanation: replace one or more digits using n`ewvalue`. Disclaimer: I assumed numeric is something consisting solely from digits.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
awk -F : '$3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { $3 = "new value"} {print}' original_file >replaced_file
```

?